# AirPrint without border / margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, printing, airprint

I am trying to print a image inside a DIV on **DIN A6** (105x148mm) (USA: 4.13x5.83 inches) . However in the simulator I always get the printout with border/margin.

Is it possible to customize AirPrint to **print without a margin/border** and fit to the paper?

I am using **Cordova** AirPrint plugin, which does not offer such a customization. Here the JS:

```
var cusImage = document.getElementById('imgDIV');
window.plugin.printer.print(cusImage, {}, function () {
                                      //callback
                                       });
```

My knowledge in Objective-C is very limited. I looked inside the `APPPrinter.m` file, I only found this:  `page.scalesPageToFit = YES;`, it was already set to yes, but apparently is does not remove the border.

Here is an image i tried to print: [Original Image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/56/Maggi-Werbung.jpg)

and here is the AirPrint output with Printer Simulator:

[image: printed]

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you found a solution? I am in the same situation..